# Check if model contains key derbyjs

Tags: derbyjs

Is there a way to check if a property exists on a model?

```
var self = model.get("users."+userId);
if (! self.name.firstName){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work; however, you need to check each property one by one, since going to far down the chain might not exist.

so perhaps:

```
var self = model.get("users."+userId);
if (!self.name && !self.name.firstName){
  //do something
}
```